# What is the recommended approach for storing media, videos and image, in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I am developing a social network where users can upload profile pictures, photo galleries and videos.  I am torn between whether or not to use raw Azure blob storage or Azure Media Services?  I need to be able to house potentially millions upon millions of images and videos.  I read that Media Services have a restriction of one million assets, this concerns me when I can't predict how many images and videos are going to be uploaded.  However, I like the video encoding capabilities of Media Services.  On the other hand, I have images that I need to store and crop into 4 different image sizes as they are uploaded.  Would Media Services fit the image needs that I have and if so what presets would I use if I need 4 different sizes or should I just use the blob storage for the images and Media Services for the videos?  What are the implications when you can possibly have millions upon millions of assets, what are possible workarounds for this size limitation?

Comment: Media service itself uses blob storage for storing files.

Comment: Should it be used for image processing as well and if so, what presets should I use when I need in image cropped in 4 different sizes?

Comment: Media Service !== Image Processing Service. My recommendation would be to read up on what media service can do for you.

Comment: That makes sense.  So, should I use azure Media Services for the Video items and something else for the image processing?  What does Azure for image processing?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, Blob storage is one way to store image files - you would need to wrap appropriate protection around those images those for the privacy of your users.  Blob storage probobably makes the best choice based on durability and cost - you just need to do a bit of work to make it suitable for a social network.

While Media Services may have a million asset limit nothing stops you from running multiple Media Service accounts in a single Azure subscription.  Start with one and when you (hopefully!) close in on a million assets you can spin up a new one (or maybe that restriction will be lifted by then).

Comment: If I were to use raw Blob Storage for the images, how can I restrict access to the images location when the url's for the images will need to be accessed from the social network?  I have struggled to find an appropriate methodology for doing this, from a security perspective.

Comment: If I were to use raw Blob Storage for the images, how can I restrict access to the images location when the url's for the images will need to be accessed from the social network?  I have struggled to find an appropriate methodology for doing this, from a security perspective.  I see where the blobs can be locked down individually from the admin or programmatically, but how do you restrict access to only individuals logged into the social network?

Comment: Take a look at [Shared Access Signatures](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/). All of the Azure storage libraries have easy APIs to create them.